# Create new pd.DataFrame column if value of existing column contains specific substring

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a DataFrame as below:

```
     entity   
0     cat  
1     dog
2     tree
3     dog
4     flower
```

I want to create a new column called `type` which contains values based on a condition that a value in `entity` contains a substring

```
substring1 = 'cat|og'
substring2 = 'ree|ower'
```

the resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
    entity      type   
0     cat      animal
1     dog      animal
2     tree     plant
3     dog      animal
4     flower   plant
```

The approach i'm taking it to take pd.Series.str.contains, and creating two boolean columns `is_animal` and `is_plant`.

How can I modify the below code to eliminate the need for the two boolean columns and just have the `type` column?

```
df.loc[:, 'is_animal'] = df.entity.astype(str).str.contains(substring1, case=False)
df.loc[:, 'is_plant'] = df.entity.astype(str).str.contains(substring2, case=False)
```

I have tried iterating over the DataFrame using `iteritems()` to create the `type` column,  but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dictionary for `type`s by substings and then set new values by compare `substring`s only for matched rows:

```
d = {'animal':substring1, 'plant':substring2}

s = df.entity.astype(str)
for k, v in d.items():
    df.loc[s.str.contains(v, case=False), 'type'] = k
print (df)
   entity    type
0     cat  animal
1     dog  animal
2    tree   plant
3     dog  animal
4  flower   plant
```